# Deleting user home directories/setting permissions via Powershell

Tags: permissions, powershell, domain

We have a large number of users that are no longer with the organisation, and we're currently investigating the best way to delete their home drives.

Unfortunately there have been issues with file permissions on some system-created folders (Downloads, Documents, Music...), which means when we are doing them manually, we need to set Domain Admins as Owner on the top level, Replace the lower settings, then give Domain Admins Full Control before we can delete the folders. We aren't able to apply to the containing folder, as there are also current users in the same area.

I've attempted to create a script (below) to do all this to each user in the OU the accounts are contained in. Running that didn't progress beyond the first user, and caused the server to reject any attempts to navigate the shares, by users and admins alike, although file permissions were untouched. A reboot of the server solved this, but I'm wary of any attempt to make further changes myself.

```
$Students = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} -SearchBase "OU=StudentHold,DC=DOMAIN,DC=lan"

ForEach ($User in $Students){

#Write the folder location to the screen.
Write-Host (Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties homeDirectory).homeDirectory
$StudentHome = (Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties homeDirectory).homeDirectory

#Make an Security object. Set the Owner to Domain Admins. Apply it to the Student Home Directory.
$OwnerAcl = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity
$OwnerAcl.SetOwner([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]'DOMAIN\Domain Admins')
(Get-Item $StudentHome).SetAccessControl($OwnerAcl)

#Get the Security settings for the Student Home Directory. Add Full Control for Domain Admins. Apply it.
$Acl = (Get-Item $StudentHome).GetAccessControl('Access')
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("DOMAIN\Domain Admins", 'FullControl','ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl -path $StudentHome -AclObject $Acl    

#Delete the Student Home Directory, and all contained folders.
Remove-Item -path $StudentHome -force -recurse
}
```

Is there any obvious change/better way to do this? We'd be doing this for around 300 users currently, and amending it to run on another 500 or so per year.

We're on a Windows domain, primarily Windows 7 workstations, and all of these particular users use the same Mandatory profile. All their individual files are stored on the network, in their Home folder.

Comment: Removing the profile directory does not remove the profile from the windows installation.  It just removes the files stored in that directory.  You should look on how a user profile is removed from Windows, that is what you need to do, doing that will also remove the profile directory.  *I sort of assume you are not using roaming profiles.*

Comment: [How to remove user profiles with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472546/how-to-remove-user-profiles-with-powershell)  [Delete Unused user Profiles on local machine (PowerShell)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Delete-Unused-user-4047f41d)

Comment: We are using roaming profiles (_clarified that in the question, apologies_), but they aren't the issue here. Nothing is saved to the workstations, everything gets saved to the home folder on the network. We're attempting to free up space on the Student server where all their Home folders point to, which prompted the question.

Comment: Sounds like something in GP or the FS isn't built 100% correctly.

Comment: GPOs have been overhauled since these users logged in, so there isn't a specific worry there. The issue is purely in amending permissions and removing directories.